# Magento - Value of All Stock

Tags: magento

Is it possible to get a value for all of the stock in my magento store?

ie.  add all (item qty * item cost)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, but I did this the other day.

The best way I found was to run the "export all products" profile, and use Excel!

I made a new column to multiply item cost by qty, then at the bottom of that column did a `sum()`

Hope this simple answer is some help!

Answer (score 1):

I spent about an hour looking for a guide on how to do this this morning and I wish I had come across this website as it would have saved me time.

For someone wanting an answer that explains the process in more depth (though exactly the same) as the one above, I wrote a tutorial on how to do it on my hubpages page:

http://candlebags.hubpages.com/hub/Finding-Out-The-Value-Of-Your-Stock-With-Magento-Reports

I hope this helps someone!

Many thanks
Lewis